# How could we make this query more efficient?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given three tables `profile`, `topic`, `message`, I want to know for all `USER` profiles whether the last message to a topic was deleted.

In case the last message was not deleted I want to get `0.5` and `0` otherwise (ie. last message was deleted or profile did never message the topic).

My query has the correct result, but it takes ~25 seconds while returning ~15.000 result rows.

How can I make it more efficient? Ideally it is < 1 second.

```sql
SELECT
  p.id AS profile,
  topic.id AS topic,
  CASE WHEN m IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0.5 END AS value
FROM
  profile p
  CROSS JOIN topic
  -- latest non deleted message per topic
  LEFT JOIN message m ON (
    m.profile_id = p.id
    AND m.topic_id = topic.id
    AND m.deleted = FALSE
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT m2 FROM message m2
      WHERE m2.profile_id = p.id AND m.topic_id = m2.topic_id AND m.timestamp < m2.timestamp
    )
  )
WHERE 
  p.type = 'USER'
;
```

**The result of `EXPLAIN`**

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=395.85..1187910.62 rows=15204 width=48)
  Hash Cond: ((p.id = m.profile_id) AND (topic.id = m.topic_id))
  Join Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..213.67 rows=15204 width=24)
        ->  Seq Scan on profile p  (cost=0.00..22.36 rows=724 width=8)
              Filter: ((type)::text = 'USER'::text)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.31 rows=21 width=16)
              ->  Seq Scan on topic  (cost=0.00..1.21 rows=21 width=16)
  ->  Hash  (cost=223.15..223.15 rows=11513 width=89)
        ->  Seq Scan on message m  (cost=0.00..223.15 rows=11513 width=89)
              Filter: (NOT deleted)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on message m2  (cost=0.00..309.51 rows=1 width=0)
          Filter: ((m."timestamp" < "timestamp") AND (profile_id = p.id) AND (m.topic_id = topic_id))
```

**Side note**: We need to execute the query quite often and the result will be inserted into another table (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT (s. above)`) for further processing.

---

**SOLUTION**

See answers!

After adding the indexes I executed all three versions *intermixed 10 times*. I am comparing on my local machine while other stuff is running, so it is not very scientific - but still results seem significant:

```
// results in ms
user          | min | max | avg  | portion of profiles that has type='USER'
Stuck         | 171 | 216 | ~180 | ~96%
Gordon Linoff | 148 | 172 | ~160 | ~96%
sticky bit    | 113 | 126 | ~120 | ~96% <-- winner
Gordon Linoff |  73 | 114 |  ~90 |  ~4% <-- winner when p.type='USER' is very selectiv
```

THANKS :)

Comment: Please use `EXPLAIN` and add these details to question, this will help to help you.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Thanks for noting. I added the `EXPLAIN` result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe try to rewrite it so that the left join uses a subquery only containing the deleted state of the last message per topic and profile using `DISTINCT ON`.

```
SELECT p.id profile,
       t.id topic,
       CASE
         WHEN coalesce(x.deleted,
                       true) THEN
           0
         ELSE
           0.5
       END value
       FROM profile p
            CROSS JOIN topic t
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.profile_id,
                                           m.topic_id)
                              m.profile_id,
                              m.topic_id,
                              m.deleted
                              FROM message m
                              ORDER BY m.profile_id ASC,
                                       m.topic_id ASC,
                                       m.timestamp DESC) x
                      ON x.profile_id = p.id
                         AND x.topic_id = t.id
       WHERE p.type = 'USER';
```

For that the following indexes should be promising.

```
CREATE INDEX message_pid_tid_ts_d
             ON message (profile_id ASC,
                         topic_id ASC,
                         timestamp DESC,
                         deleted ASC);
CREATE INDEX profile_t_id
             ON profile (type ASC,
                         id ASC);
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot make the query work - think `x.topic_id = m.id` should be `x.topic_id = t.id` but still I get no results? However, just adding the indexes makes my original query very fast: 171ms! :D Thanks!

Comment: @Stuck: Yes, you're right, `x.topic_id = m.id` should be `x.topic_id = t.id`, corrected it.

Comment: Any idea why the query results in 0 rows? I accepted the other answer because I find the query easier to read/understand and the query it self works. However, the performance gain was mainly from adding the indexes so I would like to accept this answer here as well, but I can only select one! I appreciate your help a lot! THANKS!

Comment: @Stuck: Hmm, cannot think of a reason why it should not return any results (given that `topic` is not empty and there are records in `profile` with a type of `'USER'`). Even if the sub query or the left join was off, there should be rows in the result, maybe with wrong `value`s though.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit. I triple checked it and it was a typo on my end. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Stuck: Glad to here that! If you care, it would be interesting if you compared my query with Gordon's and share the results.

Comment: I executed all three versions intermixed like 10 times. I am comparing on my local machine while other stuff is running, so it is not very scientific - but still significant: mine is slowest: min: 171, max: 216, avg: ~180; Then Gordon Linoff min: 148, max: 172, avg: ~160; sticky bit is fastest: min: 113, max: 126, avg: ~120. I add it to the question as result for readability. Thanks again you guys rock!

Comment: Ah damn, I need to check the query again, all values are `0` in the result of your query.

Comment: @Stuck: If you could set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4) with sample data I could test it.

Comment: It was another typo on my end omg. I did the performance testing again - the results are almost the same. Your query got ~10ms slower, but it is still the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

> In case the last message was not deleted I want to get 0.5 and 0 otherwise (ie. last message was deleted or profile did never message the topic).

I'm thinking something similar to stickybit, but phrased a bit differently:

```
select p.id as profile, t.id as topic,
       (case when not (select m.deleted
                       from messages m
                       where m.profile_id = p.id and
                             m.topic_id = t.id
                       order by m.timestamp desc
                       limit 1
                      )
             then 0.5
             else 0
         end) as value
from profile p cross join
     topic t
where p.type = 'user';
```

The same indexes are called for:

- `messages(profile_id, topic_id, timestamp desc, deleted)`
- `profile(type, id)`

Why phrase it like this? `distinct on` is fast with an index.  However, I suspect a simple index lookup is even faster.

Second, you don't specify how selective `type = 'user'` is.  This version doesn't deal with messages on other profiles, only the profiles you care about.

Comment: Hmm, funny I first had a very similar version with a subquery in mind but then decided the left join might be faster. So now the OP has both of them to try after all! :) But I think you made a little mistake. The filter for the type seems to relate to the type of the profile, not the type of the topic. Or maybe I did get that wrong?

Comment: @stickybit . . . A performance comparison would be quite interesting.

Comment: As stated in the other comment: adding the indexes brings my original query down to ~171ms. I tried your query and it is ~179ms. Running yours and mine multiple times both are around ~175ms in AVG. Seems that performance is only about the indexes in this case! Thanks!

Comment: @Stuck . . . What proportion of profiles have the type `'user'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff ca. 96% of all profiles have `type = user`.

Comment: @Stuck . . . In that case, there is little to be gained by ignoring the other types, and I can see why all three approaches would be comparable.  If 96% of the profiles were NOT user, then this should be noticeably better than stickybit's method.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct. I tested the query against another group of profiles (4%). In this case your query is faster (see updated results in question). I conclude that since we execute the query on different profile groups, we should select the query that is executed more often - or in case we really need that performance gain we may select different queries based on the profiles of interest.

Comment: and maybe you can add a missing `AND` before `m.topic_id = t.id` and for the index its not `profile(user, id)` but  `profile(type, id)` in your answer

Comment: @Stuck . . . Thank you for following up with the timings.  You have a really good question.